# How to change component with react-router without changing URL in address bar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having one use case.

My main react application (container) is loading (mounting) another react child application (module), which is implemented using `react-router`.

When the route changes in the child application, it is also changing the main application URL.

Is there any way to change the route without changing URL?

I know this is possible without `react-router` in the child application, by just changing component based on state.

But how can we achieve the same with `react-router`?

It should be kind of head less application, please help your thoughts.

Comment: Please, explain your case further. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help to understand your case better. You likely need memory router or custom router, depending on your case

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `react-router` without changing the URL you may consider using a `MemoryRouter`

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
<MemoryRouter>
     <div>
       <Route path="/first" component={FirstComponent} />
       <Route path="/second" component={SecondComponent} />
     </div>
 </MemoryRouter>
```

And use it like usual:

```
this.props.history.push('/second')}
```

> A router that keeps the history of your "URL" in memory (does not
>   read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser
>   environments like React Native.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md

You just need to be aware that `MemoryRouter` does not change the browser history, thus you won't be able to press the back button. If you want to keep a back button, you will need to handle it manually.

```
this.props.history.goBack() // when a user click on the back button
this.props.history.goForward() // when a user click the forward button
```