# React Router: do not change URL for specific pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

Is there a way to not change the URL for some pages?

I know that using "MemoryRouter", I can switch to different pages using `history.push` without changing the URL at all. However, I want to change the URL for some pages. Is there a way to do this?

Current code:

```js
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';

return (
    <Router basename="/d/home_page" history={history}>
              <Switch>
                  // I want to change the URL for this page
                  <Route path="/products">
                    <Products />
                  </Route>
                  // I want to change the URL for this page
                  <Route path="/files">
                    <Files />
                  </Route>
                  // I do not want to change the URL for this page
                  <Route path="/do_not_change_url">
                    <DoNotChangeURL />
                  </Route>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve instead of not changing the url ?

Comment: @BARNOWL Ideally it would navigate to that page while keeping the URL the same

Comment: have you looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640075/how-to-change-component-with-react-router-without-changing-url-in-address-bar

Comment: When I used "MemoryRouter", it does not change the URL for any the pages, no matter which page I navigate to, it's always the "home_page" url.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this?

```js
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';
...
return (
    <Router basename="/d/home_page" history={history}>
      <div>
          // I want to change the URL for this page
          <Route path="/products">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          // I want to change the URL for this page
          <Route path="/files">
            <Files />
          </Route>
          <MemoryRouter>
             <Route path="/do_change_url">
               <DoNotChangeURL />
             </Route>
          </MemoryRouter>
      <div>
    <Router
```

or

```js
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';
...
return (
    <Router basename="/d/home_page" history={history}>
      <Switch>
          // I want to change the URL for this page
          <Route path="/products">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          // I want to change the URL for this page
          <Route path="/files">
            <Files />
          </Route>
          <MemoryRouter>
             <Route path="/do_change_url">
               <DoNotChangeURL />
             </Route>
          </MemoryRouter>
      <Switch>
    <Router
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this, the URL is still changing and it's staying on the home page instead of rendering the new component. I am using `history.push('/do_not_change_url');` to get to the page. The URL changed but it did not render the component. Instead it's displaying the "home_page".